# Ждать AsyncTask.get, не тормозя графический интерфейс

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Я создаю AsyncTask для загрузки Bitmap по URL, далее я получаю Bitmap методом AsyncTask.get. Все бы хорошо, но мне нужно что бы пока метод get ждал результата, интерфейс пользователя обновлялся, так как там в это время находится анимация. Как это сделать?

```
BitmapAsyncTask bitmapAsyncTask = new BitmapAsyncTask();
bitmapAsyncTask.execute(xml.getAttributeValue(i));

//Тут нужно подождать, причем обновлять UI

try {
   newsStruct.bitmap = bitmapAsyncTask.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {Log.e(LOG, "InterruptedException bitmapAsyncTask.get error = "+e.getMessage());
   } catch (ExecutionException e) {Log.e(LOG, "ExecutionException bitmapAsyncTask.get error = "+e.getMessage()); 
   } catch (TimeoutException e) {}
```

Comment: через метод `get()` асинктаска вы не сможете выполнять обновление UI пока не придет ответ. Метод останавливает основной поток, ожидая ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынести код в `AsyncTask` , чтобы оне блокировать основной поток, и теперь методом `get()` блокировать основной поток, и дальше искать способ не блокировать основной поток, пока блокирется основной поток, пока код выполняется. Простите, я не мог не переформулировать ваш вопрос, чтобы вы ощутили всю его абсурдность...

По делу: Перенесите весь код, который выполняется после 
`newsStruct.bitmap = bitmapAsyncTask.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
В новый метод. И вызывайте этот самый метод в `onPostExecute()` методе вашего `Asynctask`
Вы абсолютно не понимаете, как работают `AsyncTask`, и для чего они нужны. Прочитайте любой урок по `AsyncTask`, который найдете в [гугле](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android%20asynctask%20tutorial)

Comment: Верно! Спасибо, нужно было просто выполнить код в потоке. Сразу не сообразил.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, у тебя получится это осуществить, если вызвать функцию в отдельном потоке, и ожидать его завершения:

```
public class test {

    private class BitmapTask implements Runnable {

        private BitmapAsyncTask bitmapAsyncTask;
        private Object param;

        public BitmapTask(BitmapAsyncTask bitmapAsyncTask, Object param){
            this.bitmapAsyncTask=bitmapAsyncTask;
            this.param = param;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            bitmapAsyncTask.execute(param);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        BitmapAsyncTask bitmapAsyncTask = new BitmapAsyncTask();

            new Thread(new  BitmapTask(bitmapAsyncTask,xml.getAttributeValue(i))).run(); // выполняем отдельно в потоке
            Thread.sleep(100);

        try {
          newsStruct.bitmap = bitmapAsyncTask.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {Log.e(LOG, "InterruptedException bitmapAsyncTask.get error = "+e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {Log.e(LOG, "ExecutionException bitmapAsyncTask.get error = "+e.getMessage()); 
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {}

    }

}
```

Однако, не помню, работает ли это в андройде или там какой то свой Task для Thread...

Comment: Интерфейс все равно замирает.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой UniversalImageLoader, в ней методом displayImage. Запрос выполняется в фоновом потоке, никаких тормозов UI не будет