# Зависает UI во время выполнения AsyncTask

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

Добрый день. Пишу Android приложение, нужно подключиться через интернет и получить данные с сервера. Загрузку данных сделал через AsyncTask, но во время выполнения AsyncTask главный поток блокируется.

```
private void doit () {
            //Загружаем данные через интернет
            String resp = ""; //То, что скачали с интернета
            pd = new ProgressDialog(this); //Инициализация прогресс диалога
            try {
                //Запускаем новый поток
                GetHTTPResponseTask task = new GetHTTPResponseTask();
                task.execute();
                resp = task.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = "Error";
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = "Error";
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Класс AsyncTask

```
//Этот класс находится в том же классе, что и текущая Activity
private class GetHTTPResponseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setTitle("Авторизация");
            pd.setMessage("Заходим...");
            pd.show(); //Запускаем прогресс диалог
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... p) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String _text = ""; //Для возврата результата
                    HttpURLConnection cn = null;
                    try {
                        //Что-нибудь подлиннее, чтобы показать, насколько всё плохо
                        URL url = new URL("http://dl.zaycev.net/127833/2206682/ruki_vverkh_-_ruki_vverkh_(zaycev.net).mp3"); 
                        cn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                        cn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        cn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
                        cn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
                        cn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                        cn.setReadTimeout(7000);
                        cn.connect();

                        InputStream in = cn.getInputStream();
                        StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        String line; //Построчное чтение
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            bf.append(line);
                        }
                        _text = bf.toString();
                        cn.disconnect();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        _text = "Error";
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        _text = "Error";
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        _text = "Error";
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        _text = "Error";
                    }

            return _text;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss(); //Закрываем прогресс диалог

        }
    }
```

Делал как описано в примерах на многих сайтах, итог один и тот же, 2 проблемы:

1. Зависаем главный поток UI, хотя в отладке показывает, что делает в отдельном потоке;
2. ProgressDialog во время загрузки большого файла не появляется. На виртуальном устройстве можно увидеть, что он появился после загрузки. Если закомментировать строку pd.Dismiss(), то тогда ProgressDialog запустится раньше, чем файл начнет скачиваться, но не остановится.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такими проблемами?

Список Thread.
[image: Список Threads]

Comment: метод `get()` AsyncTask-a блокирует основной поток до получения результата. Вам надо использовать конструкцию с переопределением `onPostExecute()` смотрите [эти ответы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433004/Ждать-asynctask-get-не-тормозя-графический-интерфейс)

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо, исправил, теперь всё отлично работает;)

Answer (score 1):

У вас в основном потоке стоит метод get, который ждет пока завершит свою работу AsynTask и вернет результат. Для получения результата используйте `listener` или используйте Loader вместо AsynkTask. И не нужно показывать лишний код, который не относится к вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо, уже ответили выше;) я не знал, какой тут лишний, поэтому скинул побольше и с комментариями